# Count if values/strings reoccur by date in python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to count names (strings) only if it reappears. Reappeared values/strings should be grouped by dates. I do not want to count the first appearance.

```
import pandas as  pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['date'] = ['2020-01-01', '2020-01-01','2020-01-01',  
              '2020-01-02', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-02', 
              '2020-01-03', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-03',
              '2020-01-04', '2020-01-04', '2020-01-04']
df['value'] = ['Abe', 'Abe', 'Abe', 
               'Abe', 'Ben', 'Abe', 
               'Ben', 'Ben', 'Coco',
               'Abe', 'Abe', 'Abe']
df


    date        value
0   2020-01-01  Abe
1   2020-01-01  Abe
2   2020-01-01  Abe
3   2020-01-02  Abe
4   2020-01-02  Ben
5   2020-01-02  Abe
6   2020-01-03  Ben
7   2020-01-03  Ben
8   2020-01-03  Coco
9   2020-01-04  Abe
10  2020-01-04  Abe
11  2020-01-04  Abe
```

So, the output should look like this

```
    date        revisitors
1   2020-01-02  1
2   2020-01-03  1
3   2020-01-04  1
```

Here is what I've tried

```
df.groupby(["date"])["value"].nunique()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
s = df.drop_duplicates(['date','value'])

s['value'].duplicated().astype(int).groupby(s['date']).sum()
```

Output:

```
date
2020-01-01    0
2020-01-02    1
2020-01-03    1
2020-01-04    1
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you could so something like this:

```
(df.drop_duplicates().set_index('date')
   .duplicated('value').sum(level=0).astype(int).loc[lambda x: x!=0])
```

Output:

```
date
2020-01-02    1
2020-01-03    1
2020-01-04    1
dtype: int32
```